# Рекурсивный вызов функций из списка

Tags: php, массивы, функции

Имеется массив со списком существующих функций, например:

```
$array = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3', 'func4'];
```

Каждая функция возвращает булев либо `true`, либо `false`, вот примерная структура:

```
function func1(): bool {
    return true; 
}

function func2(): bool {
    return false; 
}
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы пройтись по функциям из списка вызывая их, пока последующая будет отдавать `true`.

*Важно*: запрос к следующей может быть осуществлен, если текущая функция отдала `true`.

На функции, которая выдаст `false` необходимо остановить и получить название функции, на которой остановились.

Ручной вариант выглядит так:

```
if (func1() !== false)
{
    if (func2() !== false) {
        // etc
    }
}
```

Можно ли как-то это автоматизировать, чтобы все происходило автоматически. Так как список функций всегда разный, и названия могут отличаться. Надеюсь, объяснения задачи понятны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая возможность:

```php
<?php
$array = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3', 'func4'];

function GlazaRebenka($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $name = $value;
        if ($name() != true) {
            return $name;
        }
    }
}

print_r(GlazaRebenka($array));


function func1(): bool {
    return true;
}
function func2(): bool {
    return true;
}
function func3(): bool {
    return false;
}
function func4(): bool {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Была идея конечно сделать так-же, но что-то показалось, что нельзя сделать в виде `$name()`, однако можно. Благодарю!)

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка Для меня честь помочь Вам )

Answer (score 2):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array) - 1; ++$i) {
    $func = $array[$i];

    if (!$func()) {
        echo $func;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю ...))

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = ['function1', 'function2', 'function3', 'function4'];

foreach ($arr as $function) {
    if (!$function()) {
        break;
    }
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: Отличный вариант)

Comment: @девочкасглазамиребёнка Спасибо) Отсутствие key, переменных и проверка заранее делает код более надежным и простым)

Answer (score 1):

Тут ни функция не нужна, ни тем более рекурсия. Достаточно одного цикла и одного условия:

```
$array = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3', 'func4'];

foreach ($array as $func) {
    if ($func() !== true) {
        die($func);
    }
}


function func1(): bool {
    return true;
}
function func2(): bool {
    return true;
}
function func3(): bool {
    return false;
}
function func4(): bool {
    return true;
}
```